# tight_layout() reserves ylabel and yticklabels space even when disabled

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2*4 subplots figure, with half of the ylabel and yticklabels disabled. Unfortunately, tight_layout() does not remove the extra white space which corresponds to the area where the ylabel and yticklabels would appear if they were not disabled. The ylabel and yticklabels are removed because I would like to have 4 pairs of comparison subplots. The plot looks something like this.

[image]

I am looking for an efficient way to remove the extra white space. In fact, I would like each pair of plots to be next to each other with no space at all. Here is an working example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7)) = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(8, 4))
axs = [ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7]

for i in range(4):
    axs[2*i].set_ylabel('parameter '+str(i))
    axs[2*i+1].set_yticklabels([])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The code should yield the above plot. Any tips would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by having two subgrids and forcing a null distance between the axis (I followed this [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_nested.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-gridspec-nested-py)). The `wspace` parameter is described [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=False) # you must disable automatic spacing
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 2, figure=fig)

gs0 = gs[0].subgridspec(2, 2, wspace=0.0)
gs1 = gs[1].subgridspec(2, 2, wspace=0.0)

axs = [[],[]]
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        axs[0].append(fig.add_subplot(gs0[i, j]))
        axs[1].append(fig.add_subplot(gs1[i, j]))

axs = [*axs[0],*axs[1]]

for i in range(4):
    axs[2*i].set_ylabel('parameter ' + str(i))
    axs[2*i+1].set_yticklabels([])
```

[image: Sample image with the use of gridspec and subgridspec]

Since the automatic spacing is disabled, you may have to play with axis and figure properties to adapt the position of the axis, labels, etc.

A partial (distance won't be null, but may be interesting for other users), more elegant solution is to use `constrained_layout` when creating the figure. More info in [matplotlib's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(
    2, 4,
    figsize=(8, 4),
    constrained_layout=True,
    )

axs = axs.reshape([8])
for i in range(4):
    axs[2*i].set_ylabel('parameter '+str(i))
    axs[2*i+1].set_yticklabels([])

# plt.tight_layout() # not necessary
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample image with the use of constrained layout]

Comment: There is still some space between the pairs of subplots. Is it possible to leave no space at all?

Comment: My bad, I've edited my answer with a solution does that.

Comment: Instead of using sub grids, you can also use `subplot_mosaic`.  However, I would recommend just using `constrained_layout` in this case.  It takes `w_pad` and `wspace` arguments if you want the axes squished together. However given that your ticks point outward be aware that there will be some space reserved for those..